# Error saving file

Tags: android

Where is the problem in this code?
i want write to internal storage but when run this code app unfortunatly stopped

```
public Boolean save_user_pass(String user , String pass) throws IOException
{
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter write1=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(getFilesDir()+"data" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        write1.write(user);
        write1.write("\n");
        write1.write(pass);
        write1.flush();
        write1.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a  couple problems.
First, openFileOutput() doesn't take a directory but only a filename, so you need to do:

```
OutputStreamWriter write1=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("data" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

and the file will end up in the files folder of your application in the internal storage.
Now the code works but it's worth pointing out also that in your code you did `getFilesDir()+"data"`, this would have been also wrong becuase `getFilesDir()` returns the path without a trailing slash so you should have done `getFilesDir()+"/data"`